# Python 3.x: how to use ast to search for a print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm creating a test which is supposed to check if a function contains a `print` statement or not (Python 3.x, I'm using 3.7.4). I've been using `ast` to check for similar things (referencing the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232810/python-check-if-function-has-return-statement) question), such as `return` or list comprehensions, but I'm getting stuck on `print`.

An [online AST explorer](https://python-ast-explorer.com) lists a `Print` subclass in the body, and it's taking Python 3 `print`s, so I know it's not a Python 2 thing.

The [Green Tree Snakes](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html) ast docs say that Print only has an ast node in Python 2. This is closer to what I'm experiencing. Here's a function that I was going to use to make an assertion:

```
def printsSomething(func):
    return any(isinstance(node, ast.Print) for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(func))))
```

returns:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I'm assuming this has to do with `print` being a function in Python 3.x, but I can't figure out how to use this knowledge to my advantage. How would I use `ast` to find out if `print` has been called?

I would like to reiterate that I've gotten this code to work for other ast nodes such as return, so I should be confident that it's not a bug specific to my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any named object (including functions such as `print`) is called then there will be at least one `_ast.Name` object amongst your `node`s. The name of the object ('print') is stored under the `id` attribute of this node.

As I'm sure you're aware, `print` changed from a statement to a function between python version 2 and 3, possibly explaining why you were running into problems.

Try the following:

```py
import ast
import inspect

def do_print():
    print('hello')

def dont_print():
    pass

def prints_something(func):
    is_print = False
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(func))):
        try:
            is_print = (node.id == 'print')
        except AttributeError:  # only expect id to exist for Name objs
            pass
        if is_print:
            break
    return is_print

prints_something(do_print), prints_something(dont_print)

>>> True, False
```

...or if you're a fan of one-liners (where `func` is your function to test):

```
any(hasattr(node,'id') and node.id == 'print' 
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(func))))
```

Comment: I was really hoping for a one-liner, and have spent the last hour or so trying to refactor, but I can't hack around the need for the try/except. I really like this answer since it works with the style in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I've added in a one-liner if that helps!

Answer (score 4):

`print` is a function in python 3 so you need to check for an `ast.Expr` which contains an `ast.Call` for which the `ast.Name` has the id `print`.

Here's a simple function:

```py
def bar(x: str) -> None:
    string = f"Hello {x}!"  # ast.Assign
    print(string)           # ast.Expr
```

Heres's the full ast dump:

```
Module(body=[FunctionDef(name='bar', args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='x', annotation=Name(id='str', ctx=Load()))], vararg=None, kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='string', ctx=Store())], value=JoinedStr(values=[Str(s='Hello '), FormattedValue(value=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), conversion=-1, format_spec=None), Str(s='!')])), Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='string', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))], decorator_list=[], returns=NameConstant(value=None))])
```

The relevant part (for `print`) is:

```
Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load())
```

Below is a simple example with a node visitor (sublcassing `ast.NodeVisitor`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ast
import inspect
from typing import Callable


class MyNodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Expr(self, node: ast.Expr):
        """Called when the visitor visits an ast.Expr"""
        print(f"Found expression node at: line: {node.lineno}; col: {node.col_offset}")

        # check "value" which must be an instance of "Call" for a 'print'
        if not isinstance(node.value, ast.Call):
            return

        # now check the function itself.
        func = node.value.func  # ast.Name
        if func.id == "print":
            print("found a print")


def contains_print(f: Callable):
    source = inspect.getsource(f)
    node = ast.parse(source)
    func_name = [_def.name for _def in node.body if isinstance(_def, ast.FunctionDef)][0]
    print(f"{'-' * 79}\nvisiting function: {func_name}")
    print(f"node dump: {ast.dump(node)}")
    node_visitor = MyNodeVisitor()
    node_visitor.visit(node)


def foo(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 1

def bar(x: str) -> None:
    string = f"Hello {x}!"  # ast.Assign
    print(string)           # ast.Expr

def baz(x: float) -> float:
    if x == 0.0:
        print("oh noes!")
        raise ValueError

    return 10 / x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    contains_print(bar)
    contains_print(foo)
    contains_print(baz)
```

Here the output (minus the ast dumps):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
visiting function: bar
Found expression node at: line: 3; col: 4
found a print
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
visiting function: foo
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
visiting function: baz
Found expression node at: line: 3; col: 8
found a print
```